# VB.NET - Excel formula

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2010

Hi im trying to programmingly insert a formula into the cell using the following:

```
        With wbXl.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells(9, 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(Running!C2:C999999,Running!B2:B999999,">=01/10/2014 00:00:00",Running!B2:B999999,"<=01/10/2014 23:59:59")"
    End With
```

Problem is that the " in the formula is playing havok with vb saying syntax error.

How would i get around that, any help would be great :)

Many Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two double quotes to escape them. (basically apart from the first and last " make the rest be "")

```
.Cells(9, 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(Running!C2:C999999,
Running!B2:B999999,"">=01/10/2014 00:00:00"",Running!B2:B999999,
""<=01/10/2014 23:59:59"")"
```

This should produce the following formula in the cell

```
=SUMIFS(Running!C2:C999999,Running!B2:B999999,">=01/10/2014 00:00:00",Running!B2:B999999,"<=01/10/2014 23:59:59")
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but sadly whenever i run it i get a dialogue box say "Update Values: Running" the dialogue box wants me to open a file? Cheers

Comment: Running! was in your original post, so I assume you have a Worksheet named "Running". If not just change Running! to whichever sheet or range you want to use.

Comment: Worked like a charm, the error i had i was referencing the sheet "Running" before VB changes the Sheet name, swapped it around and it worked.